# Apply exec function to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exec, apply

I have following `pandas` `DataFrame` to which I need to apply the `exec` function to all the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
var = 2.5
df = pd.DataFrame(["var*1", "var*3", "var*5"])
```

### Expected result

The expected result I need is:

```
      0
0   2.5
1   7.5
2  12.5
```

### Using exec function with apply

However if I do the following:

```
df.apply(exec)
```

or even:

```
df.apply(lambda x:exec(x))
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: exec() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

### Using map with lambda function

Other option I tried was:

```
>>> df[0].map(lambda x:exec(x))
0    None
1    None
2    None
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

But it's not the result I expect.

### Defining a function

I even tried to define a function and then apply it:

```
def execute(x):
    exec("a = " + str(x))
    return a

df[0].apply(execute)
```

But result is following error:

> NameError: name 'var' is not defined

## Question

How can I then get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [pandas.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html). You can [reference local variables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#local-variables) using `@var` syntax.

As for arbitrary code execution, you should explicitly pass local variables as dict and use `eval` to get a return value, e.g. `eval("a + 2", {"a": 1})`

As for your question:

```
df[0].apply(eval, args=({}, {"var": var}))
```